# get data from cosmos db in c# for given querystring

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following function which is fetching whole documents :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetAllPreferences(string queryString)
        {
            IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(collectionInfo.DatabaseName, collectionInfo.CollectionName))
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            List<dynamic> results = new List<dynamic>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<dynamic>());
            }

            return results;
        }
```

But here I am not able to make use of queryString.
I have the following structure of my document :

```
{
    "type": [
        "university",
        "institute"
    ],
    "preferences": [
        {
            "type": "university",
            "universityDetail": [
                .....
            ],
            "state" : [
                ....
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "institute",
            "instituteDetail": [
                .....
            ],
            "state" : [
                ....
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have to get only preferences from each document. The equivalent sql query is "select preferences from *collectionInfo.CollectionName*".

Please suggest the code edit and also help me with the exact queryString required in my case.

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code using your SDK:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetAllPreferences(string queryString)
        {
            SqlQuerySpec queryStr = new SqlQuerySpec(queryString); //"select c.preferences from c"
            FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions();
            feedOptions.EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true;

            IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(collectionInfo.DatabaseName, collectionInfo.CollectionName), queryString, feedOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

            List<dynamic> results = new List<dynamic>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<dynamic>());
            }

            return results;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq;

namespace SO67598286
{
    class Program
    {
        const string connectionString = "connection-string";
        const string databaseId = "database-name";
        const string containerId = "container-name";
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(connectionString);
            Container container = client.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);
            var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<IDictionary<string, object>>()
                .Select(f => f["preferences"]);
            var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator();
            while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                foreach (var document in await iterator.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this code makes use of [`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/3.18.0) Nuget package and I believe you're using an older version of Cosmos DB SDK.

Also, please see this post for more details: https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/using-linq-to-query-dynamic-schemaless-cosmosdb-documents/. I have used the code mentioned in this blog post only.

Comment: I dont have connection string, I have been given the DocumentClient object